# using blocks to reload UITableView data crashes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am basically trying to reload the UITableView data using blocks when the data is loaded back in a non-blocking fashion.

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * objects, NSError * error){
        if (!error){
            for (PFObject * vote in objects){
                if([vote objectForKey:@"note"]){
                    NSString * username = ((PFUser *)[vote objectForKey:@"voter"]).username;
                    NSLog(@"Username is %@", username);
                    [self.notes addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[vote objectForKey:@"note"] forKey:username]];
                    NSLog(@"Note is %@", [vote objectForKey:@"note"]);
                }
            }
             [self.tableView reloadData];
        }

        //[MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.navigationController.view animated:YES];
    }];
```

The issue is that the following code will generate an error of:

```
bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x246d20: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...
```

this is inside my cellForRowAtIndexPath:
[image]

Why is this and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is telling you that a certain method must be run on the main thread (or the web thread, to which you don't have access). Since `reloadData` triggers this method eventually, one way to solve this would be to make `reloadData` execute on the main thread:

```
[self.tableView
    performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData)
    withObject:nil
    waitUntilDone:NO
];
```

Comment: so just put that inside the block?

Comment: Yup, replace your line `[self.tableView reloadData];` with the proposed code from me.

Comment: Also, you will need to use a lock to prevent concurrent access to `self.notes` (except if it already is a thread-safe container).

Comment: I have an MBProgressHUD that is running when it's doing this, should be enough?

Comment: I don't see the relationship here, your MBProgressHUD doesn't seem to have anything to do with your table view. Did you replace the line with `reloadData` with the `performSelectorOnMainThread:` call ? Does it fix the crash ?

Comment: It does fix the crash, I am talking about the lock that you were talking to prevent access to self.notes

Comment: Since you're accessing `self.notes` from different threads you need make sure no two thread access it at the same time. Thus you need to enclose every access with a `NSLock`, a la: `[myLock lock]; doSomeWorkWithSelfNotes; [myLock unlock];`.